# Can't import an external .jar library into my Android project on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, external

I've searched everywhere I could for a solution to my problem an I couldn't find one, so I hope there's someone outhere who can help me.

I have a .jar library that I want to include into my project, I've followed a fews guides I found, but no one has worked for me so far, despite the fact that I can compile and generate my APK.

After installing the APK and launching the app, when a class member is called (the one from the library I want to import), my app crashes, and logcat gave me this :

```
Could not find class 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity', referenced from method com.azsde.myApp.Settings$1.onPreferenceClick
```

I then decompiled my apk because I was curious to see if the class has been included or not, and I found that it has not be included in my apk, here's a the result of a tree command listing my files:

http://pastebin.com/wcdK37FM

Here are my Java Build Path settings:

[image]

What did I do wrong and why isn't my library included in my APK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the JAR to your project's build path yourself as if it were a plain Java project will not work.


You add libraries to an Android project by copying the JAR to the `libs` folder at the root of your project (if the folder does not exist, then create it); ADT will then automatically add it to your build path and set up your project to bring the JAR into your APK.


You can learn more here http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesn't work either :(

I'm starting to wonder if my .jar is correct ...

I imported the this git : https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser into Android Studio and made a .jar out of it

Is it correct ?

Comment: Android Studio is in alpha. I would stay away from it for now and stick to Eclipse. Maybe Android Studio is causing your issue.

Comment: Android Studio was indeed causing the issue, after strugling for a few minutes to understand how gradle was working, I compiled manually ( command prompt) and got a library that was working this time, it has been successfully included into my apk.

Thank you very much !